Apache Tomcat 9.0.96 JSTL c:out does no longer escape text and has inconsistent behavior
Since the 9.0.96 version of the Apache Tomcat servlet container released on 2024-10-08 the c:out tag behaves differently and looks like it's a potential security issue (code injection ?)
It looks like in certain circumstances it does no longer escape the value attribute.
Version 9.0.95 (and previous ones) does not have this behavior.
Here's how to reproduce the problem. Use a simple test file (use it as index.jsp in the ROOT webapp for instance, along with taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar and taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar in the app's lib folder) :
<%@ page session="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<%
String test = "{ \"key\" : \"value\" }";
java.util.Map<String, String> map = new java.util.HashMap<>();
map.put("test", test);
request.setAttribute("test", test);
request.setAttribute("map", map);
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="<c:out value="${test}" />" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="<c:out value="<%=test %>" />" />
    <br/>
    <c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
        <input id="${entry.key}" name="${entry.key}" type="text" value="<c:out value="${entry.value}" />">
        <br/>
    </c:forEach>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    Tomcat Version : <%= application.getServerInfo() %>
    <br/>
    Servlet Specification Version : <%= application.getMajorVersion() %>.<%= application.getMinorVersion() %> 
    <br/>
    JSP version : <%=JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getEngineInfo().getSpecificationVersion() %>
    </body>

</html>

In Tomcat 9.0.95 it renders like this (showing just the important part) :
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="{ &#034;key&#034; : &#034;value&#034; }" />
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="{ &#034;key&#034; : &#034;value&#034; }" />
<input id="test" name="test" type="text" value="{ &#034;key&#034; : &#034;value&#034; }">


In Tomcat 9.0.96 it renders like this :
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="{ &#034;key&#034; : &#034;value&#034; }" />
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="{ "key" : "value" }" />
<input id="test" name="test" type="text" value="{ "key" : "value" }">


Even worse, when refreshing the page (the above result is obtained only once, after the JSP is compiled), then it renders like this :
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="{ "key" : "value" }" />
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="{ "key" : "value" }" />
<input id="test" name="test" type="text" value="{ "key" : "value" }">



I reproduced your problem and swapping out Apache's unmaintianed JSTL impl for EE4J's maintained JSTL impl did fix the problem for me. But this in turn won't fix the bug in Tomcat itself which will possibly still expose the same problem in any other non-JSTL tag.

After more extensive research, the problem, not directly linked to the described behavior can be found here :
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69399
Probably it's best to avoid 9.0.96 until it's fixed.

Great find. That's indeed the cause of what's internally happening in Apache's JSTL impl. The release() call will indeed reset the escapeXml attribute to false. In case you wish to keep using Tomcat 9.0.96 for some reason then you'd need to explicitly set the escapeXml="true" attribute. But that's a work around not a solution.
